# $A,B$ $n\times n$ matrices, $A^2 = AB$, $B^2 = I + BA$, prove $A=0$.

Tags: matrices

Besides finding $B$ is invertible couldn't find something useful. By finding the invertible of $B$, $(B - A)$, and multiplying it with $A^2 = AB$, I got that 
$A(A^2-AB+I) = 0$. Couldn't go further with that, any suggestions?

Comment: You already know that B-A is invertible, say, (B-A)C=I, and the first condition says that A(B-A)=0 hence A=A(B-A)C=0.

Comment: Thanks solved that pretty quick after posting!

Answer (score 3):

$$\begin{array}{rcl}
B^2 &=& I+BA \\
B^2 - BA &=& I \\
B(B-A) &=& I
\end{array}$$

Hence $B$ and $B-A$ are inverses of each other.

$$\begin{array}{rcl}
A^2 &=& AB \\
A^2 - AB &=& O \\
A(A-B) &=& O \\
A(B-A) &=& O \\
A(B-A)B &=& O \\
A &=& O
\end{array}$$